# Firefox plugin to build custom links for the right click menu

Tags: firefox, plugins

In Firefox, I'd like to be able to highlight a word or number, then right click and have options that would open various custom links such as:

View User Profile -> http://mysite.com/user/HIGHLIGHTEDWORD

View User Admin Page -> http://mysite.com/admin/user.php?user=HIGHLIGHTEDWORD

View Order Page -> http://mysite.com/orderdetailspage.php?order_id=HIGHLIGHTEDWORD

Something like that would save me and my team a lot of time.

Does anyone know is such a plugin exists, and if not what would be involved in developing one?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This page](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_:_Tips_:_Customize_context_menu) has some options for Menu customization extensions:

Maybe you could use one of those extensions with [keyword searches](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Using_keyword_searches)?

Answer (score 2):

I believe in [you](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9730)!

I know you're trying to save yourself some time with due diligence researching whether it's been done, but with the power of copy and paste, you could "write your own" almost as quickly as asking the question.